# IBM IoT Real-Time Insights and multiple map events

Tags: real-time, ibm-cloud, iot

I am using IBM IoT Real-Time insights and sending in an event which contains:

`{
    "d": {
        "speed": 105,
        "lat": 34.147543,
        "lng": -99.300058
    }
}`

When I send in an event, the map correctly updates with the correct marker as expected:

[image]

However, when I send in a second event without changing any of its content, the map changes and shows the following marker position:

[image]

My gut is telling me that the second event is providing coordinates of 0, 0 ... but it is exactly the same event as the first.  If I select a new dashboard and go back to the first with the map, this pattern repeats.  The next event shows fine and the one after that shows me West Africa.  I am able to trivially recreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resetting of latitude and longitude coordinates with the maps widget is a limitation that is currently being addressed by the IoT Real-Time Insights team. Keep an eye on the [What's new in Bluemix](http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/whatsnew/index.html#services_category) section for news about new features as they are released.

Comment: @Kolban The map widget limitation has been addressed in a recent product update. The latitude and longitude no longer resets.